# Adding same RelativeLayout multiple times dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I want to add many relative layouts in my main view. I tried writing code by taking help from some questions posted on this website and did this but it is not running. Please help

calc.xml
Relative Layout that I want to occur multiple times

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#4169e1"
    android:id="@+id/relativeView" >

     <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/etItem"
            android:hint="Item Name"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:background="#00bfff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" />

     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et21"
            android:hint="MRP "
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/etItem"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom" />

     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et22"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/etItem"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/et21"
            android:background="@drawable/custom"
            android:hint="QTY." />

     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et23"
            android:hint="Discount(%)"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/etItem"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/et22"
            android:background="@drawable/custom" />

     <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/et21"
            android:text="Check Savings"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

     <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tvans2"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/et23"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

dummy.xml in which the Relative Layouts will be set

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearView" >

    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Class Dummy.java
Here I have tried to create 10 relative layouts and set their IDs in for loop.

```
public class dummy extends Activity{

private LayoutInflater minflate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dummy);

    View v = (View) minflate.inflate(R.layout.calc, null);

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearView);
        v.findViewById(R.id.relativeView).setId(i+100);
        main.addView(v);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happen when you run that code? Does it show any error? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: On opening the app, a dialog appers " umfortuately app has stopped". I want that multiple but identical relative layouts is shown one below another, just like in Gmail.

Comment: I think you trying to do it the wrong way. Gmail uses a ListView or a GridView to display the mails. Because I don't know what you really want to do I could not help you much more.